# systemd service permission error when binding to ipc port inside a VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, vagrant, ipc

I'm using vagrant to emulate services with network communication. My base box is the ubuntu/bionic64. The application that I'm porting to the VM is written in C++ and binds to ipc addresses as follows:

```cpp
sink.bind("ipc:///var/run/dummy-service");
```

So after compiling and installing this service in /usr/bin/, I used `systemctl` to create the desired service with the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=dummy manipulator
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/dummy-service.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dummy-service
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

as for the location of the service file: `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/dummy.service`

So when I run the following command:

```
systemctl --user enable dummy.service
systemctl --user start dummy.service
```

It gives an exit code error when running its status:

```
 dummy.service - belt and electrodes status manipulator
   Loaded: loaded (/home/vagrant/.config/systemd/user/dummy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-01-28 23:52:58 UTC; 18s ago
  Process: 22420 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dummy-service (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Jan 28 23:52:58 ubuntu-bionic systemd[20920]: Starting dummy manipulator...
Jan 28 23:52:58 ubuntu-bionic systemd[20920]: dummy.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 28 23:52:58 ubuntu-bionic systemd[20920]: dummy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 28 23:52:58 ubuntu-bionic systemd[20920]: Failed to start dummy manipulator.
```

What I discovered after was that of a permission error because the service is not allowed to run in `/var/run/`. When I switched the binding to `sink.bind("ipc:///tmp/dummy-service");`, the service apparently ran without issue:

```
 dummy.service - dummy manipulator
   Loaded: loaded (/home/vagrant/.config/systemd/user/dummy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2021-01-29 00:06:04 UTC; 30s ago
```

What should I do to run my service with the binding to the `/var/run` address?

I've already trying installing the binary as a superuser, I've tried changing the binary's permissions with `chmod 777`. I've tried altering options in the service file:

```
User=root
Group=root
```

All without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running the service as a user service (`--user`). A user service is never going to be able to create files in the root filesystem (`/tmp` is the only exception).

The unit file needs to go in either `/etc/systemd/system` (that's if you're putting it there manually), or in `/lib/systemd/system` (that's if you're installing it with a package manager).

Then you can start/stop/enable with `sudo systemctl start dummy` etc.

If you really need to run this as a user service, you might consider giving the binary the necessary capability (see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)). Another option worth investigating is polkit, but the best option is definitely to run it as a system service.